# htaccess modifications working on some pages but not on others?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have been trying to execute php code within a document with an .htm or .html extension. I finally got it working using:

**AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm**

Now, being able to execute php within .htm documents, only works if I go directly to the .htm page such as: http://www.foobar.com/layout.htm

However, it does not work if I go to the index.php page which **uses** that layout.htm page...

This is an example of what the index page url looks like: http://www.foobar.com/index.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you *use* the page exactly?

Comment: The Layout page includes tags such as {HEADER} and other similar names in curly brackets. I am not really familiar with using that...other than that it is a normal html/css page.                I do know that if I add html to the layout.htm file (without using any php) it shows up on the index.php page fine.  However, if I modify the layout page by using php, the changes only appear if I go directly to the layout.htm page but never appear on the index.php page.

Comment: You need to post the section of the php code that *uses* the htm file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using something like `include` in your php file to include the html file, your `.htaccess` rules will not have any effect on the included file.

The `.htaccess` rules only get executed on requests that are made to the apache web-server and when you include a local file in php, you are simply requesting a file on the local file system; you are not requesting it through apache.

**Edit:** Based on the comment below your question, it is also possible that you are using something like `readfile` to get the contents of the htm file. If that is the case, you need to change that to `include` so that the php gets executed.

Comment: I am using the php include function.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess rule does not apply for included files in php.

Did you check this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags.